# jarsigner.exe exited with code 1 error in .NET MAUI app

Tags: android, keystore, maui, android-keystore

I'm trying to sign my .NET MAUI app for Google Play submission but keep getting the following error:

[image]

Here's a quick background:

The keystore I used to submit the original version of my app got compromised so even though I still have the original keystore, I had to contact Google to reset my upload key.

I generated a new upload key in a new keystore i.e. `keystore.jks`, exported the `upload_certificate.pem` file and submitted it to Google and they notified me that they reset my upload key on their end.

I'm now trying to use the new `keystore.jks` to sign my app. In my project file, I have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>..\keystore.jks</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>mynewalias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I issue the following command to create a signed package:

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=MyPassword /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=MyPassword
```

I issue this command in the root of my project and the `keystore.jks` file is one level up i.e. where my `.sln` file is so the path is correct.

Any ideas/suggestions on what maybe causing this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the alias. I made sure that I made a note of the alias I used but admittedly I wasn't really interested in fully understanding the `keytool` commands I was issuing. I copied and pasted most of them from the Google email and used them to generate the new keystore and the upload certificate.

When I ran `keytool -list -v -keystore myapp.keystore` command, I noticed that the alias in the keystore was different than the one I had in the `csproj` file.

Once I changed it to the correct alias from the keystore, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this similar problem, but it wasn't with the alias. I solved mine using the following steps below.

Using the suggested project group format from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0#add-a-reference-to-the-keystore-file),

1. Ensure that the **AndroidSigningKeyStore** tag has the correct path to the generated keystore. `<AndroidSigningKeyStore>C:\Users\path\folder\mymauiapp\myapp.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>`
2. Use the password you used while creating the keystore in the CLI for the **AndroidSigningKeyPass** and **AndroidSigningStorePass** tags.
   `<AndroidSigningKeyPass>keystorepassword</AndroidSigningKeyPass>`
   `<AndroidSigningStorePass>keystorepassword</AndroidSigningStorePass>`